# STS 3.7.1 unable to add Dependencies to classpath on Import maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I updated STS and when imported project using Import->Existing Maven projects I'm unable to add Maven Dependencies to classpath. I click on `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Library -> Maven...` STS says to me 'Use `'Maven project settings'` to configure dependency resolution'. But nothing there, only active profile selection, which gives nothing.

Seems like STS team completely broke import and I need to create new project and move src files there.

version: 3.7.1.RELEASE

**Update:**

I mean I can add dependencies to pom, but cant add them to classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They fixed this in 3.7.2.RELEASE. Click `Maven->Update Project` and all dependencies will be automatically added to classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Open the pom.xml file. It would open in a tabbed form editor. See the "Dependecies" tab in the editor.